# Activate custom Ribbon Tab on Workbook Open

Tags: excel, vba, menu, ribbonx

I've created a custom menu on the ribbon by just right clicking and selecting customise ribbon. I want the custom menu to be selected on open of the workbook using microsofts reference code for doing it:

```
Public myRibbon As IRibbonUI 
 
Sub tabActivate(ByVal control As IRibbonControl) 
 myRibbon.ActivateTab (control.ID) 
End Sub
```

Does anybody know how I can get the control.id so I can run the code?

Alternatively (actually preferably) I'd like to be able to do it with reference to the name of the menu.

Thanks and regards, Mark

Answer (score 1):

The [IRibbonUI.ActivateTab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.iribbonui.activatetab) method activates the specified custom tab, not ribbon controls or menus. If you hover over the control on the customize ribbon dialog window you may find the control IDs displayed in a popup window as a hint. Also built-in control IDs are published in the [documents available for download](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-fluent-ui-command-identifiers) at GitHub.